# How can I change the class of an element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

In my ASP.NET app I'm using AJAX and some web services to update an unknown number of instantiated user controls (hence the reason I'm using FindControl below).

When a function returns a result, I'm trying to change the color of a label control.  This works:

```
$get("<%= me.FindControl("lblName").ClientID %>").style.color = 'red';
```

Now I would like to be able to specify the colors from a CSS file.

```
.MyRed 
{
    color:Maroon;
}
```

And here is the part I can't figure out.  I've tried using addClass and toggleClass but the browser reports "Object doesn't support property or method 'toggleClass'" etc.

```
$get("<%= me.FindControl("lblName").ClientID %>")......  = '.MyRed';
```

As always, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you appear to be using the [ASP.NET AJAX library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397536.aspx), you can call [Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310966.aspx):

```
Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(
    $get("<%= me.FindControl("lblName").ClientID %>"), "MyRed");
```

Answer (score 2):

`$get` is Microsoft specific but returns a DOM object..

So you can use this DOM object with jQuery like this:

```
$($get("<%= me.FindControl("lblName").ClientID %>")).toggleClass('MyRed');
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: When I say "Microsoft specific" I mean via the client ajax library and not Microsoft-only browser compatible...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#<%= me.FindControl("lblName").ClientID %>').addClass('myRed');
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do that with jQuery, you need this instead:

```
$("#<%=lblName.ClientID %>").addClass("MyRed");
```

Answer (score 1):

what is `$get`? if you're trying to use `jQuery` you need to either use `$` or the `jQuery` object.

```
$('#<%= me.FindControl("lblName").ClientID %>').removeClass("removeMe").addClass("addMe")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the id on the selector, befor the id value you shall add the "#" char